# Self-duality of the subgroup lattice of finite abelian groups

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

For each abelian finite group $G$ let $\mathcal L(G)$ be the lattice of all subgroups of $G$.

For which abelian finite groups $G$, is $(\mathcal L(G),\subseteq)$ order-isomorphic to $(\mathcal L(G),\subseteq^{-1})$?

($\subseteq^{-1}$ is the same as $\supseteq$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any finite abelian group $G$ is (noncanonically) isomorphic to its dual $\hat{G}=\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.  By duality, the lattice of subgroups of $G$ is anti-isomorphic to the lattice of subgroups of $\hat{G}\cong G$.

Comment: Will it work for normal subgroups lattice of a finite group?

Comment: No, because there's no such duality in the non-abelian case ($Hom(G,Q/Z)$ only reflects the abelianization of $G$). As an exercise, you should find a group of order 8 whose lattice of normal subgroups is not isomorphic to its opposite lattice.